# Удалить повторения подстроки в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка условно говоря такого вида:

```
petya kolya vasya oleg misha vasya vasya ivan vasya
```

Как на php удалить из неё все повторяющиеся подстроки vasya, кроме первой, чтобы осталось

```
petya kolya vasya oleg misha
```

Спасибо.

Comment: $text  = "petya kolya vasya oleg misha vasya vasya ivan vasya";
$array = explode(' ', $text );
$result = array_unique($array);
echo implode(' ', $result);

Answer (score 0):

**unique.php**

```php
<?php

// Исходная строка
$source = 'petya kolya vasya oleg misha vasya vasya ivan vasya';

// Пробел
const SPACE = ' ';

// Лень далее писать 7 букв, хочу писать 3.
// EOL - End of Line
// Знак обозначающий окончание строки, на разных операционных системах он разный
// Документация по константе PHP_EOL: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol
const EOL = PHP_EOL;

// Документация по echo: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php
echo 'Source string:' . EOL;
echo $source . EOL;
echo 'Space:' . EOL;
echo SPACE . EOL;
// Результат:
# Source string:
# petya kolya vasya oleg misha vasya vasya ivan vasya
# Space:
#

// Для начала раздели слова по пробелам, в этом нам поможет функция explode
// Документация по explode: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php
$separated = explode(SPACE, $source);
// Посмотрим что у нас получилось:
// Документация по print_r: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php
echo 'Result after explode:' . EOL;
print_r($separated);
// Результат:
# Result after explode:
# Array
# (
#     [0] => petya
#     [1] => kolya
#     [2] => vasya
#     [3] => oleg
#     [4] => misha
#     [5] => vasya
#     [6] => vasya
#     [7] => ivan
#     [8] => vasya
# )

echo EOL;

// Затем оставим в этом массиве только уникальные значения
// Документация по array_unique: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php
$unique = array_unique($separated);
// Посмотрим что у нас получилось:
echo 'Result after array_unique:' . EOL;
print_r($unique);
// Результат:
# Result after array_unique:
# Array
# (
#     [0] => petya
#     [1] => kolya
#     [2] => vasya
#     [3] => oleg
#     [4] => misha
#     [7] => ivan
# )

echo EOL;

// Далее превратим массив в строку соединив слова через пробел
// Документация по implode: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php
$concatenated = implode(SPACE, $unique);
// И посмотрим что у нас получилось:
echo 'Result after implode:' . EOL;
echo $concatenated . EOL;
// Результат:
# Result after implode:
# petya kolya vasya oleg misha ivan

echo EOL;

// Если ivan почему-то не нравится, можно его убрать.
// Для этого уберём последний элемент массива
// Документация по array_pop: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pop.php
// Внимание! array_pop работает по ссылке!
array_pop($unique);

// Посмотрим что у нас получилось:
echo 'Result $unique state after array_pop:' . EOL;
print_r($unique);
// Результат:
# Result $unique state after array_pop:
# Array
# (
#     [0] => petya
#     [1] => kolya
#     [2] => vasya
#     [3] => oleg
#     [4] => misha
# )

echo EOL;

// И превратим в строку:
echo 'Result after implode:' . EOL;
echo implode(SPACE, $unique) . EOL;
// Результат:
# Result after implode:
# petya kolya vasya oleg misha

echo EOL;

// Дополнительно:

// Если планируется получить набор слов из аргументов при запуске скрипта
# php unique.php romaxa romaxa romaxa coder coder coder
// $argv - без объявления уже существующая переменная в PHP в которой хранятся все агрументы
// с которыми выполняется интерпретатор/команда "php"
$arguments = $argv;
echo 'All arguments:' . EOL;
print_r($arguments);
// Результат:
# Array
# (
#     [0] => unique.php
#     [1] => romaxa
#     [2] => romaxa
#     [3] => romaxa
#     [4] => coder
#     [5] => coder
#     [6] => coder
# )

echo EOL;

// Нулевой элемент массива содержащий имя запущенного скрипта нам не нужен, уберём его
// Документация по array_shift: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php
// Внимание! Как и в случае с array_pop в первый аргумент - $arguments передаётся по ссылке.
array_shift($arguments);

// Проверим во что превратилась переменная $arguments
echo '$arguments after array_shift:' . EOL;
print_r($arguments);
// Результат:
# Array
# (
#     [0] => romaxa
#     [1] => romaxa
#     [2] => romaxa
#     [3] => coder
#     [4] => coder
#     [5] => coder
# )

echo EOL;

// Оставим только уникальные значения и превратим оставшиеся элементы в строку в одну строчку:
// И сразу выведем результат
echo 'From terminal arguments:' . EOL;
echo implode(SPACE, array_unique($arguments)) , EOL;
// Результат
# From terminal arguments:
# romaxa coder

echo EOL;

// Если планируется получить набор слов из ввода из терминала:
// Документация по readline: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php
$input = readline("Enter line with duplicated words: ");
echo implode(SPACE, array_unique(explode(SPACE, $input))) , EOL;
```

**Вывод:**

```
Source string:
petya kolya vasya oleg misha vasya vasya ivan vasya
Space:
 

Result after explode:
Array
(
    [0] => petya
    [1] => kolya
    [2] => vasya
    [3] => oleg
    [4] => misha
    [5] => vasya
    [6] => vasya
    [7] => ivan
    [8] => vasya
)

Result after array_unique:
Array
(
    [0] => petya
    [1] => kolya
    [2] => vasya
    [3] => oleg
    [4] => misha
    [7] => ivan
)

Result after implode:
petya kolya vasya oleg misha ivan

Result $unique state after array_pop:
Array
(
    [0] => petya
    [1] => kolya
    [2] => vasya
    [3] => oleg
    [4] => misha
)

Result after implode:
petya kolya vasya oleg misha

All arguments:
Array
(
    [0] => unique.php
    [1] => romaxa
    [2] => romaxa
    [3] => romaxa
    [4] => coder
    [5] => coder
    [6] => coder
)

$arguments after array_shift:
Array
(
    [0] => romaxa
    [1] => romaxa
    [2] => romaxa
    [3] => coder
    [4] => coder
    [5] => coder
)

From terminal arguments:
romaxa coder

Enter line with duplicated words: romaxa romaxa coder romaxa coder coder romaxa coder
romaxa coder
```

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант, можно в цикле создать новый текст из не повторяющихся слов

```
$text = 'petya kolya vasya oleg misha vasya vasya ivan vasya';
$words = explode(' ', $text);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    (in_array($word, $prevWords)) ?: $newText .= $word.' ';
    $prevWords[] = $word;
}
echo trim($newText); // petya kolya vasya oleg misha ivan
```